# PHP: Geting exact shape and value of textarea

Tags: php, post, text, get, area

I made a form which has text area in it and while $post gets the value of it
it doesnt keep the shape of the text.

How can i get the value of text area and keep its shape in php?

Thanks for any help RAS!

Comment: What do you mean by "shape" ? Whitespace ?

Comment: Do you mean linebreaks? if so try `wrap="hard"`

Comment: I mean that if i echo the value its still going to be the same shape as it was in the text area